# android/kotlin- Retrofit with compositeDisposal(RXjava2) not go to response/throwable block while clicking back button

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2, back-button

In Kotlin, while opening an activity or a fragment,I can call an api in this format and get response without any issue:

```
 compositeDisposable.add(dataManager 
                    .getHistory()
                    .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
                    .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
                    .subscribe({ response ->
                        isSwipeRefreshCalled.set(false)
                        setIsLoading(false)
                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                            setHasErrorMessage(false)


                            navigator.getHistory()

                        } else {
                            setHasErrorMessage(true)
                            navigator.showErrorMessage(response.responseMessage)
                        }
                    }, { throwable ->
                        setIsLoading(false)
                        isSwipeRefreshCalled.set(false)
                        navigator.handleError(throwable)
                    })
            )
```

,but whenever I clicked backButton and go back to that activity/fragment,although compositeDisposable has been called, nothing has happened and **neither response block got called nor throw an exception.**

be noted that `compositeDisposable.dispose()` is called when activity/fragment destroyed (onDestroy()/onDestroyView())

Be glad someone assist me.

Comment: I dont understand your problem please explain more

Comment: When are you calling the methods to get data and are you using `replace` or `add` to display the fragments?

Comment: @Fred: onViewCreated of fragment , I call viewModel.getHistoryMethod()
and I use replace to display a fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is too big for a comment. I'm not sure this is the issue, but I did notice something in the description of the problem.

From the comments and the question I gathered that you are doing something like:

```
onViewCreated:
   // add to composite disposable

onViewDestroyed:
   // dispose the composite disposable
```

The problem is that when you call `compositeDisposable.dispose()` you actually render this composite disposable unusable. In other words, every time you try to add a disposable to it, it won't work because the composite disposable already disposed. This can be an issue if the composite disposable stays in memory, i.e., if you have it as a field of a `viewModel` that doesn't get recreated. The next time you come and use the same composite disposable it won't work.

Instead, you can use [`compositeDisposable.clear()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/disposables/CompositeDisposable.html#clear--), which will remove all disposables from the container and dispose of them. However, the container is not disposed and can be used for more disposables.

Comment: Thanks @Fred, you were right. 
I fixed it as you mentioned and problem is solved.